# Дана матрица Х(10х10). Найти в каждой строке матрицы минимальный элемент и упорядочить строки по возрастанию этих элементов

Tags: c, сортировка, матрицы

Есть такая задача. Нашёл решение, где по возрастанию сортируется только первая строка. Подогнал свою задачу под него, но, моих знаний к сожалению не хватает, что бы заставить идти по возрастанию все строки. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
#define M 10
main() {
int x[N][M], i, j, k, id, max;
srand(time(NULL));
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<M; j++) {
        x[i][j] = rand()%50 - 25;
        printf("%4d", x[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");

k = M-1;
while (k > 0) {
    id = 0;
    for (j=1; j<=k; j++)
        if (x[0][j] > x[0][id])
            id = j;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        max = x[i][id];
        x[i][id] = x[i][k];
        x[i][k] = max;
    }
    k -= 1;
}  

for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<M; j++) {
        printf("%4d", x[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

получается вот так:[image: сортируется по возрастанию только первая строка]

Answer (score 1):

С помощью стандартной функции `qsort()` можно сортировать массивы быстро и удобно,т.к. требуется лишь создание функции для сравнения элементов массива `comp(a,b)`. Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 10    //квадратная матрица

int comp (const void * a, const void * b) //для qsort сравнения
{
    int _a = *((int*)a);
    int _b = *((int*)b);
    if (_a > _b) return  1;
    if (_a < _b) return -1;
    return 0;
}


int main(void) {
    int x[N][N];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
            x[i][j] = rand()%50 - 25;
            printf("%4d", x[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    qsort(x[i], sizeof(*x)/sizeof(**x), sizeof(**x), comp); //не буду изобретать велосипед

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
            printf("%4d", x[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добрый день. Большое спасибо за ответ и пояснение!